# Windows - USB control request problem

Tags: c++, windows, usb

I try to send/read a control message with a specific setup packet to an USB device.

I've found at MSDN this documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff537344%28v=vs.85%29.aspx and at the usbuser.h the struct "_USB_SEND_RAW_COMMAND_PARAMETERS" which can be filled with the parameters for a setup packet. The problem ist that MSDN says about this function: "Do not use this request".

The next try was the request code "USBUSER_PASS_THRU" but I don't know what the parameters mean and I don't think that it is possible to send a specific setup packet with this request code.

I can't use WinUSB because I would like to solve this without any installation or other requirements to the target PC.

Has anybode solved this problem or has an hint to solve this?

Thank a lot.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid driver installations, you could make your device emulate an Human Interface Device (HID) or Mass Storage Device; both of those types of devices work automatically with the built-in Microsoft drivers.

If you figure out another way to do it, I'd be interested to hear the answer.